# Why did json2sharp generate an extra class from my JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, datacontractserializer

I used [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate some classes from my JSON.  Everything is working when I deserialize with `DataContractJsonSerializer` or `JsonConvert`, but I cannot understand why the generator makes the `Message2` class.  It does not fit in with my logic, and I want to clearly understand this.  I think that `Message2` should be used inside of `OfflineMessage` like `List<Message2> messages`, and the `Message1` class needs to be deleted.  What am I missing?

These are the classes generated by json2csharp (note that I renamed `Message` to `Message1` for a clearer question):

```
public class Message2
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string sender { get; set; }
    public string receiver { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public int timeStamp { get; set; }
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public string msgContext { get; set; }
}

public class Message1
{
    public Message2 message { get; set; }
}

public class OfflineMessage
{
    public int sequence { get; set; }
    public List<Message1> messages { get; set; }
}

public class Respons
{
    public OfflineMessage offlineMessage { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int __invalid_name__@pendingMsg { get; set; }
    public int __invalid_name__@syncStatus { get; set; }
    public List<Respons> responses { get; set; }
}
```

This is how the JSON looks:

```
{
  "@pendingMsg": 0,
  "@syncStatus": 0,
  "responses": [
    {
      "offlineMessage": {
        "sequence": 2,
        "messages": [
          {
            "message": {
              "status": 6,
              "sender": "storng",
              "receiver": "JoilSp",
              "msg": "Hello my friend",
              "timeStamp": 1465398075,
              "hash": "+eq4cxwICbyNC31X5naQz3Z+R/Lxdw==",
              "msgContext": "+eq4cxwICbyNC31X5naQz3Z+R/Lxdw=="
            }
          },
          {
            "message": {
              "status": 6,
              "sender": "JioS",
              "receiver": "JoilSp",
              "msg": "nice)))",
              "timeStamp": 1465398075,
              "hash": "+eq4cxwICbyNC31X5naQz3Z+R/Lxdw==",
              "msgContext": "+eq4cxwICbyNC31X5naQz3Z+R/Lxdw=="
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's creating a `Message2` class because your `messages` property is an array of objects, and *those objects* contain other objects in their `message` property. It needs one class to represent the members of the `messages` array, and another to represent the values of the `message` properties.

If you are in charge of your JSON format, it may be cleaner to structure your JSON like this:

```
{
   "@pendingMsg":0,
   "@syncStatus":0,
   "responses":[
      {
         "offlineMessage":{
            "sequence":2,
            "messages":[
               {
                  "status":6,
                  "sender":"storng",
                  "receiver":"JoilSp",
                  "msg":"Hello my friend",
                  "timeStamp":1465398075,
                  "hash":"+eq4cxwICbyNC31X5naQz3Z+R\/Lxdw==",
                  "msgContext":"+eq4cxwICbyNC31X5naQz3Z+R\/Lxdw=="
               },
               {
                  "status":6,
                  "sender":"JioS",
                  "receiver":"JoilSp",
                  "msg":"nice)))",
                  "timeStamp":1465398075,
                  "hash":"+eq4cxwICbyNC31X5naQz3Z+R\/Lxdw==",
                  "msgContext":"+eq4cxwICbyNC31X5naQz3Z+R\/Lxdw=="
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This should produce the kind of class structure that you are expecting.